# How to add a post's view count into the WordPress API response

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, rest-api, wp-api

This is my first time working with Wordpress APIs, and i'm not a PHP developer. Essentially our client just wanted us to display WordPress articles in our react-native app with simple data like the:

- date
- title
- content
- thumbnail
- etc..

...anything you'd find in the default response, and this was easy. We simply used the default endpoints like this one: https://demo.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=1015

Anyways... Our client now wants to display the "view count" of each article. However, i can't find that data in the default response:

[image]

Is there a way to get this view count data, and have it return in the API response, without having to customize every single endpoint?

Thanks

Comment: That's because WordPress does not record views. You'll have to use a plugin for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the post view count logic. After that you have to call that meta count in in rest API using the below API code.
This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44007869/3431899) will help to get count response in the rest api.